# What is the equivalent of Ansible's "when" clause in SaltStack?

Tags: ansible, migration, salt-stack

For the given below Ansible code, how can I implement a similar functionality in SaltStack (specifically `when` clause)?

```
---
- include: install-redhat.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

- include: install-debian.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"
```

Do I have to use Jinja2 templates for this? It looks like `unless` and `onlyif` can only test return codes of shell commands.

Comment: I don't know Salt but it sure does look like they [just use Jinja2](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2019.2/topics/tutorials/states_pt3.html#using-grains-in-sls-modules) like ansible does; however, their convoluted language is so convoluted I couldn't even imagine to what one would apply an `{% if %}` so good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to use jinja for this.
Something like

```
{% if grains['os'] == 'Redhat' %}
include:
  - install-redhat
{% endif %}
```

But I would rather include the states in top file
for example, in top.sls, you can do

```
'os:Redhat':
  - match: grain
  - state1_redhat
  - state2_redhat

'os:FreeBSD':
  - match: grain
  - freebsd1
  - freebsd2
```